# why this output has a grabage at last printf?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x=10;
    int *p=&x;
    foo(&p);
    printf("%d ",*p);
    printf("%d ",*p);
}
void foo(int** l)
{
    int j=20;
    *l=&j;
    printf("%d ",**l);
}
```

can you explain why the output is [20 20 garbage] ?
why cant i get 20 20 20?
Both the statements of print after the foo function call are same.

Comment: The only output of your program that is *not* garbage is the first 20. The second 20 printed by your program is undefined behavior, i.e. garbage that happens to look like 20.

Comment: Because dereferencing a pointer  pointing to a variable that is out of scope is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: so, why my second output is not 20? I am just trying to dereference my pointer variable p.

Comment: how can my pointer p be out of scope?  can you bring more detailed answer?

Comment: you also didn't declare the `foo` function

Comment: @SirishPotnuru You have gone to some lengths to make `p` point to `l`, which is a *local variable* within the function `foo`.  An essential property of local variables is that they disappear when the function containing them returns.  Typically they're stored on the stack, which means that the value may stay there for a little while -- until some later function call reuses that portion of the stack and obliterates it.

Comment: Thanks that really helped